# getting the karaf-maven-plugin to copy everything into the distribution

Tags: maven, apache-karaf

Here's a pom. It doesn't work: it gets a wiring error that one of the compile-scope features can't find a package provided by one of the runtime scope features.

My problem here is that I don't understand, from the doc, how to say: copy the bundles *at karaf assembly build time*.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>anvils-prototype</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.basistech.ws</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>rosapi-assembly</artifactId>
    <packaging>karaf-assembly</packaging>
    <name>karaf assembly</name>
    <properties>
        <skip-dependency-convergence>true</skip-dependency-convergence>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.karaf.features</groupId>
            <artifactId>framework</artifactId>
            <version>${karaf.version}</version>
            <type>kar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.karaf.features</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>${karaf.version}</version>
            <classifier>features</classifier>
            <type>xml</type>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf.karaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>apache-cxf</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
            <classifier>features</classifier>
            <type>xml</type>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>rosette-base-linguistics</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <classifier>features</classifier>
            <type>xml</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>rosapi-worker</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <classifier>features</classifier>
            <type>xml</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.karaf.tooling</groupId>
                <artifactId>karaf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
                    <bootFeatures>
                        <feature>bundle</feature>
                        <feature>config</feature>
                        <feature>diagnostic</feature>
                        <feature>feature</feature>
                        <feature>jaas</feature>
                        <feature>shell</feature>
                        <feature>log</feature>
                        <feature>management</feature>
                        <feature>package</feature>
                        <feature>shell-compat</feature>
                        <feature>ssh</feature>
                        <feature>system</feature>
                        <feature>wrap</feature>
                        <feature>war</feature>
                        <feature>cxf</feature>
                    </bootFeatures>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Many of the features defined under `bootFeatures` doesn't exist or they are not defined in the features dependencies (standard, cxf, rosapi features). That is why it cannot create the assembly as it doesn't know about those features.

You can try to start with some well-known features such as:

```
config
management
war
cxf...
```

Comment: The wiring error happens is not explained by that.  I can take a set of features that all work with scope runtime, and then have wiring errors if I try to move one of them to 'compile'.